# Camera permission issue in iOS < 10

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, camera, ios-permissions

I have a problem asking permission for the camera.
When I install the app on my iPhone 6s plus with iOS 10.1 it works.
But if I try on my iPad 2 with iOS 9.3.5, the permissions are not asked and the room camera shows only black.

```
if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized
{
    print("tutto apposto");
}
else
{
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted :Bool) -> Void in
        if granted == true
        {
            print("concessa");
        }
        else
        {
            print("negata");
        }
    });
}
```

In the iPad I receive always "negata".
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Go to the Settings page for your app in the Settings app. Enable access to the camera.

Comment: I do no have the app in my settings because i install it from xcode

Comment: Once your app makes a request for a permission, your app should appear in the Settings app. It doesn't matter whether the app is installed from Xcode or not.

Comment: in the Iphone appears but not in the ipad...

Comment: Save the result of `AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)` to a variable. What is its actual value? Is it Authorized, Denied, Restricted, or Not Determined?

Comment: The result is "AVAuthorizationStatus"

Comment: But which specific value do you get when you run the code?

Comment: Look : http://prntscr.com/d3186n

Comment: I'm not clicking on some random link. What value are you getting? It's one of four possible values.

Comment: the link is a screen. anyway : print(AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo));  == AVAuthorizationStatus